# lazy loading:missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ng-packagr

I created two application (first application is a library and another application consuming component from the library).

The intention is to do lazy loading of an imported library.

when I trigger `ng serve` it gives an error message, but when I trigger  `ng serve --prod --aot --build-optimizer` command no problem. this problem occurs in `ng build` also.

```
Error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/bundle/bundle.d.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\AngularApp\bundle\BaseApp\app2\node_modules\bundle\bundle.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format.
```

1. The library is built with `ng-packagr`:

   ```
   npm run cd
   ```
2. created a library *.tgz file.

   ```
   npm pack
   ```
3. imported library in another application using.

   ```
   npm install *.tgz
   ```

consuming application: `tsconfig.json`

```
  //consuming application
            {
                // consuming application    
                "compileOnSave": false,  
                "compilerOptions": // consuming application  {

                "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
                "sourceMap": true,
                "declaration": false,
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "target": "es5",
                "typeRoots": [
                  "node_modules/@types"
                ],
              //consuming application  
                "lib": [
                   // test  
                  "es2017",
                  "dom"
                ],     

              },
              //consuming application
              "include":[
//test
                    "src/**/*",
                    "node_modules/bundle",
                ],
              // consuming application
                "files": [ 
                  //consume application impored library
                  "node_modules/bundle/bundle.d.ts"  // test
                  //consume application impored library
                 ] 
                 }
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: same question any solution for this issue?